# Can a Tab Page be a parent of MDI child windows?

Tags: c#

I am using C# to create a form application which has a couple of tab pages. I want to contain MDI child windows in one of the Tab page. Is it possible? I tried something like childForm.MdiParent = this.tabPage1.Handle, but I got a compile error because the type doesn't match. Would you have a good idea to do this?

Comment: `MdiParent` is of type `Form`, and TabPage does not inherit from it, unfortunately. Do you want each tab to be an MDI form?

Comment: I only want one of the tab pages to be a container of MDI child.

Comment: I'm afraid it won't be possible with the standard set of controls, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

This project on *codeproject* can be useful:

- [Multi Document Interface (MDI) tab page browsing with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12514/Multi-Document-Interface-MDI-tab-page-browsing-wit)

but I suggest [DockpanelSuite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/) on *sourceforge* for this purposes.

Comment: I checked Multi Document Interface (MDI) tab page browsing with C#. It is different from my purpose. What I want to do is put MDI child windows into one of the Tab Page, not the entire parent form.

Comment: Any update on your requirement ? i seem to be running into the same issue here . How did you manage to accomplish this ?